# Two WebCams Simultaneously

Tags: java, webcam, jmf

I'm trying to get two webcam images simultaneously using JMF. Is this possible?

Im getting the address `vfw://0`, I think this is the default webcam, but if I change 0 to 1, nothing happens.

Thank you

Comment: Two images from a single webcam? or singles images from two different webcams?

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct media locators for the different cameras in separate initialization processes. then start each datasource or player.

Be aware that vfw://1 is for TV capture and is not what you are thinking.
so pass vfw://0 (representing the default webcam) in the first media locator.
in the second media locator, pass the name of the attached USB camera.